# iOS Keyboard extension height after rotation

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I try to figure out the height of the keyboard-extension view after a rotation (device orientation changed to landscape/horizontal) happened. I use `func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)` to find out if a rotation occurred. Before and after the rotation I check the the height with:      `self.view.frame.height`.

Does someone know why I get the wrong size? Is the func called before layouting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the keyboard did/will show notifications to obtain the keyboard frame.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your answer! Can you please name the specific method? I can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: it Isn't a method; there are NSNotifications that are posted [UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardwillchangeframenotification) is probably of most interest in this case

Comment: Actually, I just realised you are talking about a keyboard extension, so I am not sure if those notifications will be posted; But if you are writing a keyboard extension and using auto layout then everything should be worked out for you.

Comment: I'm using auto layout. But don't I have to update the `.constant` of a constraint (height & width) after a rotation happened?

Comment: You shouldn’t constrain the height or width of your keyboard view: this should be implied by the constraints that you have applied to the elements in your view.

Comment: Ok, I set the top and bottom of a button but what's the reference? I tried the button above/under as a reference but this won't work. If I use the main view I have to set a specific distance which requires again updating the constants. Do you have an idea? Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: You would normally have a continuous line of constraints from the top of the superview to the top of your first subview (e.g. button), and then from the bottom of that subview to the top of the one below it and so on until the last subview that has a constraint between its bottom edge and the bottom of the superview.  You can set heights for the buttons if you want or let the intrinsic content size of the button work it out.  iOS then sizes the keyboard to suit your constraints; you don't need to size your keyboard to meet some dimension set by iOS.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried. But the keyboard is only 20px height.